# Ubuntu 16.04 won't let me run my CodeLite program

Tags: 16.04, permissions, programming

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 that I recently installed together with Windows 10, because I was told Linux was better for programming ( I'm a Computer Engineering student). When I run my program on CodeLite (which we use at university) an error appears saying:

```
/usr/bin/codelite_exec: 22: /usr/bin/codelite_exec: ./NumerosGrandes: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions? I'm new to Linux.

Comment: Where is this file located? On an NTFS paritition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar to CodeLite, but message "Permission denied" says you don't have rights to a file.

I guess you don't have executable rights for file `./NumerosGrandes`. You need to change permissions by command `chmod u+x ./NumerosGrades` in directory where the file is located. The file should be located at `project_directory/bin` or at similar place.

If it doesn't help, please provide rights of the file. You can obtain rights by command `ls -l` from the same directory.

If you don't own the file, you'll need root rights to do chmod, but I guess that is not your case.

If you don't know where to type the commands, the application is called `Terminal` or `Console` or `*something*Term`. Some filemanagers supports as default *right click* -> Open Terminal here

**Edit**

If I made you afraid of linux because of terminal, there should be way in GUI. Open filemanager and navigate to file `NumeroGrandes`, right click on it and select properties. On tab *Permissions* you can set required permissions (executable should be enough).

Comment: I had written the programs on another computer, I tried writing one on my computer and it worked. For the ones that weren't written on my computer, all I had to do was go to the executable file I was trying to open with the program, go to properties, permissions and check the 'Allow executing file as program', quite a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot!